# Redirecting using state through React-Router-Dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am going through the React-Redux Toolkit tutorials and have set up authentication (partially) - I would like to add a redirect on authentication.

I am using `"react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",`

In my `LoginForm.js` I am trying to redirect using `Redirect` by `react-router-dom`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { loginUser } from "../../features/auth/authSlice";

export default function LoginForm() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const auth = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState({
    username: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setUserInput((prevState) => {
      return { ...prevState, [e.target.id]: e.target.value };
    });
  };

  const onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(loginUser(userInput));
  };

  if (auth.isAuthenticated) {
    return <Redirect to="/" />; // this line of code causes the error
  }
```

Console:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

When I change the code to this it logs `true`:

```
  if (auth.isAuthenticated) {
    console.log(auth.isAuthenticated)
  }
```

I don't understand what the error is saying. Could someone explain it to me so that I may be able to fix this?

**EDIT**: When I try using the `Redirect` with no other code in the form it also gives the same error.

Comment: can you show your imports?

Comment: updated to show imports

Answer (score 1):

I found another post where they used `Navigate` instead of `Redirect`. Therefore I changed:

```
  if (auth.isAuthenticated) {
    return <Redirect to="/" />;
  }
```

To:

```
  if (auth.isAuthenticated) {
    return <Navigate to="/" />;
  }
```

And it started working.

Comment: good to hear that you managed, also I see that you are using react-router-dom v6, you were applying v5 functionality: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#remove-redirects-inside-switch

Comment: Not too thrilled about those docs but thanks!

Comment: documents save lives don't underestimate :') most of the time it reduces the time you spend on the problem

Comment: Oh for sure! That is the first place I went to look before I posted here. I should have said, "I am not too thrilled about how hard it was to find the upgrade changes needed in the docs." Have a great day!